# Deploying a regular JAR to Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I know this is a weird question but is it possible to somehow run a JAR with a main class on Tomcat like a WAR?

I'm aware that won't automatically give it any website capability.

I just want it to execute it inside the web server JVM with the isolation that it gives

Comment: What kind of isolation, from what, are you looking for here? Why not just re-package you code as a WAR?

Comment: Implement a `ServletContextListener`, and call that `main` when context is initialized. (Better using a managed thread from tomcat). And deploy the app as war